# Adding new cipher suites in SSL (TLS) using CNG

Tags: ssl, cng

As far as I know since Windows Vista CNG(Cryptography Next Generation), a personal user can add a new own cipher algorithm, which makes an own coded message (according information, for example, from [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730763(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730763%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)).

But CNG SDK has not commented whether we can also add new cipher suites in SSL.
Is it possible, IE (Internet Explorer) could use new algorithms for a
security connection through 'https'? What methods are possible to it
in CNG? I need assistance to add new chiper suites in ssl(tls), making a new
provider for ssl(tls) and so on.

Thanks for you help.